# Open source Facebook-like Chat (with Jabber or IRC)

Tags: javascript, chat, irc, xmpp, facebook-chat

Like [Mini Jappix](https://mini.jappix.com/) but without the big application server behind.

Is there one ?

Best would be if it's integrated with Ruby On Rails, but not required at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out cometchat at http://www.cometchat.com/ but it is commercial

Comment: I will not use it because it's not open source, and I have to use open source libraries. But it's a good solution for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is something similar to what you need, it is free and open source: http://videosoftware.pro/rvc/ they also have a commercial version (called PRO) that has deep facebook implementation. There is a link somewhere in the photo gallery or google for "svc video chat". It is advertised as chatroulette but has similar modules to a normal chat as well..

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, if I want a chatroulette for my university, it could be fun :D, but actually I just would like a simple chat with Jabber :(.